# How to create a custom delete activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation

I'm using this code to uninstall apps in Android programmatically:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open the built-in delete activity:

[image]

What I want to do is to start a custom activity instead of this built-in one. Can this be done?

I hope the question was clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", app.getPackageName(), null);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WhateverYourDesiredActivityNameIs.class);
```

where `WhateverYourDesiredActivityNameIs` is the "custom activity" that you want to show.

Bear in mind that your custom activity will not be able to uninstall the app, except by turning around and using the code that you already have.

Comment: Well, exactly the problem I'm trying to resolve but thanks

Comment: @ToniJoe: What you are asking for is the ability to uninstall the app silently, without any system UI asking for user confirmation. Ordinary Android apps cannot do this, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to uninstall the app from the custom activity

Comment: @ToniJoe: Right, but then you want to do so without an system UI asking for user confirmation. As I wrote, ordinary Android apps cannot do this, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Yes exactly. I'll try for figure out something else. Thanks CommonsWare, you've been helpful.